# Counting the number of occurrences of number n preceded by number m in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have rolled a die great many times and have input the results in Excel. I would like to count the number of 1's that come after one, 2's that come after one, 3's that come after one and so on. So somehow I would need to be able to refer to the previous cell to make Excel count e. g. this 2 only if the previous cell contained 1. How to do this? I would prefer a worksheet solution to a VBA one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> this 2 only if the previous cell contained 1

For example, if the data occupies the range A1:A10, to count 2s immediately under 1s, use formula

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,2,A1:A9,1)
```

In VBA, use

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A1:A9"),1,Range("A2:A10"),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is basically an enhanced version of [Akina's](//superuser.com/a/1329652). It automatically adjusts for the number of die rolls inputted, and displays all the different counts at the same time.

Set up a worksheet like this:

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

Enter the following formula into `C3` and then fill it into `C3:H8`:

```dart
=COUNTIFS(
  $A$3:INDEX($A:$A,ROW($A$3)+COUNT($A:$A)-2),C$1,
  $A$4:INDEX($A:$A,ROW($A$3)+COUNT($A:$A)-1),$B3
)
```